# Calculating a Process's Memory Usage

Tags: c, memory, process, linux-kernel

I have a pointer to a process that is running. I want to know how much of the total physical memory is that process taking up.

I tried this but I am getting 0 as a return value.

```
unsigned long mem_usage(struct task_struct *process)
{   
    return process->mm->total_vm/2048 * 100000; // this is wrong vm means virtual memory.
}
```

`process->mm->total_vm` returns bytes right? Is there an easier way to calculate this?

Comment: Is this the linux kernel? If so there's probably a tag for that. Also, try reversing the order of operations. `process->mm->total_vm * 100000 / 2048`

Comment: Yes. Just hangs when I reversed. That was my first thing to try.

Answer (score 0):

According to [mm_types.h](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/linux/mm_types.h#n375)

```
unsigned long total_vm; /* Total pages mapped */
```

is the size in *pages*.

This means, if you want the size in bytes, you have to convert the pages to bytes

```
total_vm << PAGE_SHIFT
```

*Update:*

The reverse way, converting bytes to pages, is

```
pages = bytes >> PAGE_SHIFT;
```

But this works only for full pages. If `bytes` is some pages plus some remaining bytes, you must either increment the number of pages or

```
pages = (bytes + PAGE_SIZE - 1) >> PAGE_SHIFT;
```

For just 2 [GiB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix#Deviation_between_powers_of_1024_and_powers_of_1000) this would be

```
pages_2gb = (2 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024) >> PAGE_SHIFT;
```

Comment: how can I represent 2GB in pages? I think that would be easier.

Comment: This is a different question. Why would that be easier?